# Is there a way to give a user/service account access to GCP projects they create?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I want to create a service account that has access to create new projects and full access to those projects it creates.

Is it possible to do this without giving that account full access to ALL projects existing and created by other users?

Edit: is the user that creates a project the owner of that project by default? If that's the case then can I give a user just project create permission and this will work as I expect it to?

Edit 2: maybe folders can also work for this? Can I give a user access to create projects under a certain folder too?

Comment: The permissions required to create projects means that the service account can access all projects in that section of the organization (org or folder level). The owner of a project is any IAM member assigned Project Owner role (granted or inherited). Edit your question to be specific on what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

Giving your user "Project Creator" role at folder level, will grant the ability to be able to create projects only inside of that project.

Additionally, it is true that the user that creates the projects will by default be the project owner.

Comment: My mistake! correction: "Giving your user "Project Creator" role at folder level, will grant the ability to be able to create projects only inside of that folder."